# Operator IS with a TFormClass

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, tform

I've a follow situation:

```pascal
TMyFormClass = class of TMyForm

function IsMyClass(AClass: TFormClass);
begin
  Result := AClass is TMyForm      // Operator not applicable to this operand type
  Result := AClass is TMyFormClass // Operator not applicable to this operand type
end;
```

The both lines does not build, the error is **Operator not applicable to this operand type**.

How can I do this comparation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lhs of the [`is`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator) operator should be an instance, but you have provided a class.

What you need is the [`InheritsFrom`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom) class method:

```
AClass.InheritsFrom(TMyForm);
```